# How to integrate png/jpeg files to an unity mobile app project

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to develop an geography quiz mobile app with Unity. So I need to display images of country flags and four different answers and integrate that images(png/jpeg) in my project. My questions is how can I do that? Would you recommend me to implement a server for that and get them via REST-Requests or just add all country flags to a folder in my project and grab them from there? If so how can I let these images display with four different answer opportunities?

I would appreciate if you could tell me how you would develop that kind of an app with Unity.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all flag images in the sprites folder. Now create a script and attach it to your UI component in Unity and in that script add a public array variable images of type Sprite.

```
public Image question1;
public Image question2;
public Image question3;
public Image question4;    
public Sprite[] images;
```

Now attach all the images you have to this public variable through Unity.

So whenever you a display a question, load the sprites to each question component according to index of the images.

```
public void setFlags(int indexOfFlag1,int indexOfFlag2,int indexOfFlag3,int indexOfFlag4){
    question1.sprite = images[indexOfFlag1];
    question2.sprite = images[indexOfFlag2];
    question3.sprite = images[indexOfFlag3];
    question4.sprite = images[indexOfFlag4];
}
```